# How to format a date-time to display the timezone in IANA format?

Tags: datetime, go, timezone

The following code

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2 Jan 2006 03:04:05PM MST"))
```

prints

```
26 Nov 2021 04:00:31PM GMT
```

How to format the timezone as `Europe/London` i.e. in the [IANA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)? The expected output is

```
26 Nov 2021 04:00:31PM Europe/London
```

Comment: afaik, there's no option to retrieve this from the `.Format` method. You could use a third-party lib though, e.g. [go-timezone-local](https://github.com/thlib/go-timezone-local), to get the IANA name of your time zone and prepend it to the string.

Comment: @MrFuppes - I checked your library and appreciate the initiative. However, it has a lot more to evolve e.g. I couldn't figure out how you can parse a string like `"26 Nov 2021 04:00:00 PM Asia/Kolkata"` using this library. A correct parsing will return something like `26 Nov 2021 10:30:00 AM Europe/London` (assuming the system's local timezone is `Europe/London`).

Comment: parsing string to datetime is another story, that was never the intention of the linked library. Neither did you mention parsing in your question, so I didn't take it into account ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes - I haven't indeed mentioned parsing in my question but often parsing and formatting go hand-in-hand. If this library is supposed to simply return the timezone ID in IANA format, I would name it differently. Anyway, thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: I was going through https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10195947 and I couldn't help laughing because the author claims that Go's date-time library is the richest. Whatever research I have done so far, Java's [Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) is richer and simpler by far.

Comment: that post reads more like an unpopular opinion for the go time podcast ^^ The comments about Python's datetime are also kind of hilarious. But it's about six years old, so the author's opinion might have changed.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an option to do this directly with the `time` format layout.

However [`Location.String`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Location.String) will print the IANA name **in most cases**.

> String returns a descriptive name for the time zone information, corresponding to the name argument to LoadLocation or FixedZone.

And `LoadLocation` **usually** takes the IANA string as input:

> If the name is "" or "UTC", LoadLocation returns UTC. If the name is "Local", LoadLocation returns Local.
>
> Otherwise, the name is taken to be a location name corresponding to a file in the IANA Time Zone database, such as "America/New_York".

Now `"Local"` isn't a valid IANA name, but `"UTC"` is — well, actually `UTC` is an alias of `Etc/UTC`.

The other gotcha with the std `time` package is that `Location.String` will print the name passed to [`FixedZone`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#FixedZone), and that can be literally anything.

So, if you are able to make assumptions about how your `time.Location` are instantiated, the following might be a viable solution:

```
fmt.Printf("%s %s", t.Format("2 Jan 2006 03:04:05PM"), t.Location())
```

Otherwise you will have to use some third-party package, or roll out your own mapping.

Comment: `t.Location` gives me for example `LocalCET 3600` (on Ubuntu Linux, in tz Europe/Berlin) - which I think is far from a IANA tz name.

Comment: @MrFuppes @Beginner if `t` comes from `time.Now()` this won’t work because the location may not be loaded with the IANA database to begin with. That’s why I say “if you can make assumptions”

Comment: you're right, if *Location is set in the time instance, the string repr will be the IANA name (with mentioned exceptions).